# Incorrect RVIZ visualization of UR10 robot

Tags: ros-melodic, rviz, moveit

There seems to be some issue with visualizing the UR10 robot on RVIZ. Recently I uninstalled ROS and all its dependencies by mistake. Then installed everything back to get it working. However, after this the visualization seems to be broken. An important note is that **only the visualization is broken.** I can use the Motion planning plugin in RVIZ to plan and execute any robot pose. Even the frame visualization is accurate. Any help on this is appreciated. Please let me know if I need to add more details to help understand the issue better. I am using ROS melodic in Ubuntu 18.04.[image]

Comment: I found [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/83891/moveit-rviz-motionplanning-plugin-broken-robot-geometry?rq=1) stack answer that worked for my issue.